# LibreOffice Calc equivalent to Excel "Custom Views" feature

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

Custom Views are an Excel feature that comes very handy when, for example, you want to save a filtered version of a worksheet and then pass to another vision of the same worksheet with different set of filters (or even to a non-filtered one) quickly without having to modify filters by hand; Views, in fact, are stored inside the workbook (and though saved within) and it's easy to recall them whenever needed. (Here is [an example of how Excel Custom Views works](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-save-custom-views-of-an-excel-2013-workshee.pageCd-storyboard,pageNum-8.html#slideshow).)

The question is: do Calc provide an equivalent feature?